# Sporadically assigning values to variables (placeholders vs feed_dict)

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a model where I need to assign to the weights (trainable variables) new external values every N iterations.

I can think of a few solutions:

1. Save and restore

   Not good as I would need to serialization, go through a file system calls, etc. (even if I use something like tmpfs)
2. Using placeholders and assign operations

   I would create a placeholder and assign op for each trainable variable. Everytime I want to assign something to the weights, I ran the assign ops.

   However, I understand that this means I will be forced to consider these placeholders in every feed_dict and pass dummy values *everytime* I run any operation in my graph.

   In addition I would be using much more memory than necessary..
3. Use a feed_dict for trainable variable and trigger ops that assign each variable to itself?

   Does this work? Is there any drawback?

Before coding something I thought it was a good idea to ask?
What is the recommended way to assign new external values to variables efficiently (memory/timewise)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent versions of Tensorflow `Variable` class has `load` method. It does exactly what you want.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#load

Answer (score 3):

Your 3-rd option sounds like the best one.

You can feed values to [tensors that aren’t placeholders](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data#feeding).

> TensorFlow's feed mechanism lets you inject data into any Tensor in a
>   computation graph. A python computation can thus feed data directly
>   into the graph.

Any tensors that are feedable can be fed. To check if a tensor is feedable or not, use: `tf.Graph.is_feedable(tensor)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the assign operations with placeholders.

> I will be forced to consider these placeholders in every feed_dict and pass dummy values everytime I run any operation in my graph
>
> In addition I would be using much more memory than necessary..

No. You would only need to feed values to the placeholders when you run the assign operations. Don't make the assign operation part of your training graph and only run them when you want to assign new values.

If the assigning turns out to be a bottleneck (for small N it might slow down your program) you can consider [other methods](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data#reading_from_files) of getting data into TensorFlow.

Comment: I understood that placeholders had to be fed all the time and not only for operations that depend on them. Excellent. Thanks!

Comment: @mtk99 No problem. But in the other answer is actually a better solution. I didn't know you can feed tensors directly.